# SAS Create a counter that depends by amount

Tags: sql, count, sas, counter

I need to create a counter in SAS that has to count if is the same agreement, same day and it depends if is credit or debit and the amount of debit or credit. They have to be dynamic because I don´t know times that there is a different amount on the same day.So, It may be a solution is with arrays... but I don´t know how to do it.

Below, you can find the counters that I need: Count credit and Count debit.
[image]

```
data have;
infile datalines delimiter=',';
informat Agreement $char4. Effective_Date1 ddmmyy10. Debit Credit;
format Agreement $char4. Effective_Date1 ddmmyy10. Debit Credit;
input Agreement Effective_Date1 Debit Credit;
datalines;
A1,01/02/2020,100,0  
A1,01/02/2020,632,0  
A1,01/02/2020,0, 100     
A1,01/02/2020,0,632
A1,01/02/2020,100,0
A1,01/02/2020,632,0  
A1,01/02/2020,0,3    
A1,01/02/2020,3,0    
A1,22/02/2020,3,0    
A2,02/03/2020,50,0
;;
```

Thanks a lot!

Regards,

Answer (score 0):

This can be achieved using a hashtable to store the values in a lookup. Please see the implementation below.

The result is not quite the same as your example output as the 3 debit has already been seen as a 3 credit earlier in the day and this is represented in the output which is consistent with the output earlier in your example table.

```
Proc Sort Data=have; 
 by Agreement Effective_Date1;
run;

data want (drop=rc); 

 set have; 
 
 attrib 
    count_credit 
    count_debit
    amount
                length=8.; 

     
 by Agreement Effective_Date1;
  
 if _n_ = 1 then do; 
    *declare hash table to keep track of what has been seen and how 
        many times as a credit or a debit; 
    declare hash seen_d();
    seen_d.defineKey('amount');
    seen_d.defineData('count_debit', 'count_credit');
    seen_d.defineDone(); 
 end; 
  
  
 if first.effective_date1 then do; 
    *clear counters and hash table at the beginning of the by group; 
    count_credit = 0; 
    count_debit  = 0; 
    amount       = 0;
    
    rc=seen_d.clear();
 end;
 
 *Assume that only a credit OR debit can exist on a given row;
 amount = max(credit, debit);
 
 rc=seen_d.find();
 
 if rc=0 then do; 
    *if amount found in hash then increment the relevant counter
     and update the entry in the hash table; 
    count_credit = count_credit + (credit > 0);
    count_debit = count_debit +   (debit  > 0);
    seen_d.replace();
  end; 
  else do; 
    *if not found set the relevant counter and add to the hash table; 
    count_credit = (credit > 0);
    count_debit =  (debit > 0);
    seen_d.add();
  end; 
 Run;
```

Comment: Did this help with your problem?